# Build CPython failed on GitHub action.(Output tons of error messages)

Tags: gcc, cmake, build, anaconda, cpython

I want to build a conda package for [nogil](https://github.com/colesbury/nogil) (A proof-of-concept implementation of CPython that supports multithreading without the global interpreter lock (GIL).)

Here is my github action: https://github.com/ovo-Tim/nogil-recipe/actions/runs/7679362846/job/20930181670

There is nothing wrong when build on my computer. But I don't know what's wrong when I build on github action.
It outputs tons of error messages like:

```
2024-01-27T20:19:35.1738278Z /usr/share/miniconda3/conda-bld/nogil_1706367303499/work/Modules/unicodename_db.h:21747:47: note: (near initialization for 'phrasebook_offset2')
2024-01-27T20:19:35.1835287Z /usr/share/miniconda3/conda-bld/nogil_1706367303499/work/Modules/unicodename_db.h:21747:54: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
2024-01-27T20:19:35.1836900Z 21747 |     79252, 79257, 79261, 79266, 79271, 79276, 79282, 79287, 79293, 79299,
2024-01-27T20:19:35.1837615Z       |
```

```
2024-01-27T20:39:30.1351309Z /usr/share/miniconda3/conda-bld/nogil_1706367303499/work/Include/exports.h:21:36: error: expected declaration specifiers before '__attribute__'
2024-01-27T20:39:30.1351531Z    21 |         #define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
2024-01-27T20:39:30.1351642Z       |
```

```
2024-01-27T20:40:30.4604993Z /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:75:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before '__MATHCALL_VEC'
2024-01-27T20:40:30.4605111Z    75 | __MATHCALL_VEC (tanh,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
2024-01-27T20:40:30.4605193Z       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This problem has troubled me for a long time. Thanks a lot.

There are [complete log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16xZJQF-wTo2vDJYmxqsxB106qGy8jku6/view?usp=sharing) and [build log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOwK0lA099ANStmDoVLIz1HkVhgjadjN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do not expect us to follow your link, run your action and trying to understand the problem from its output. Stack Overflow requires all relevant information about the problem to be in the question post itself, see [ask]. As for the error message, make sure to post the very first of them, and to post all lines of the messages, including a chain of files which cause it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your advice, I will modify the question. But I got a log file that has 7G, so that's impossible to post the whole log file.

Comment: I found there isn't any problem when I just build CPython without conda. https://github.com/ovo-Tim/nogil-recipe/actions/runs/7690257457/job/20953798635

Comment: My guess is a mis-matched compiler version between your computer and GH Actions. You'll want to make sure you're using the compilers distributed with `conda-forge` so that you have libc ABI compatibility. As for exactly how to do that, I'm not sure. To start, you should read the conda-forge documentation about building C-extension packages, I'd guess

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it works if modified the command into:

```bash
if [[ ${target_platform} == osx-* ]]; then
    ${SRC_DIR}/configure --build=${BUILD} \
                            --host=${BUILD} \
                            --prefix=${BUILD_PYTHON_PREFIX} \
                            --with-ensurepip=no \
                            --with-tzpath=${PREFIX}/share/zoneinfo \
                            --with-platlibdir=lib && \
else
    ${SRC_DIR}/configure --with-ensurepip=no \
                        --prefix=${BUILD_PYTHON_PREFIX}
fi
```